# Best way to make an array of associated values, based on multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

What i need is that when i click on a cell, for example cell [2,2] which contains "PMS03", i want to have an alert which displays ALL cells that contain PMS03, this would be alert("Positions: [2,1], [2,2], [3,7]");

I figured that somehow i would make a 2nd array during the process of creating the "pointmapS" (=puntmapS) but i think the best idea would be to get some experts like you guys to help me with this as there should be quite a few solutions (and more efficient) to this that i am probably not aware of.

[image]

Creating the mapping array:

```
var jPunten = JSON.parse(data); 
var puntmapS = []; 
var cardsS = []; 
var prevCard = jPunten[0].KARTNR; //previous card starts with the first card
cardsS[0] = jPunten[0].KARTNR;
//Generate point arrays
for (var i=0;i<jPunten.length;i++)
{
    if(prevCard!=jPunten[i].KARTNR){
        // (fill in cardsS, saves kartnr of the rows) gap-safety for if there should be gaps in the KARTNR's, currently only used for scounter
        cardsS[sCounter+1]=jPunten[i].KARTNR;sCounter++;
    } 
    //create an array under key jPunten[i].KARTNR, if it doesn't exist already
    puntmapS[sCounter] = puntmapS[sCounter] || []; // to avoid gaps we use sCounter instead of jPunten[i].KARTNR
    //then, assign your value
    console.log("S|| prevCard: "+ prevCard + " === " + jPunten[i].KARTNR +" (Kartnr)");

    puntmapS[sCounter][jPunten[i].BITNRK-1] = jPunten[i].STATDEV; //add point to row, -1 because array starts at 0

    console.log("S|| "+"  --SCounter: "+ sCounter + " bit: " + jPunten[i].BITNRK + "    = " + jPunten[i].STATDEV);
}
```

Creating the table:

```
if(puntmapS.length!=0){
    table = "<table style='margin-left:20px;font-size:80%;' border='1'><tbody><tr><th></th><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th><th>6</th><th>7</th><th>8</th><th>9</th><th>10</th><th>11</th><th>12</th><th>13</th><th>14</th><th>15</th><th>16</th></tr><tr><th>"+cardsS[0]+ " S</th>";
    for (var i=0;i<sCounter+1;i++)
    {
        for (var x=0;x<16;x++)
        {
            if(puntmapS[i][x]!=undefined)
            {
                table+= "<td><a href='#' onClick='alert(\""+puntmapS[i][x]+"\")'>"+puntmapS[i][x]+"</a></td>";
            }
            else
            {
                table += "<td style='background-color:#E6E6E6'><a href='#' onClick='alert(\"EMPTY\")'>&nbsp;</a></td>";
            }
        }
        if(i<(sCounter)){
            table+="</tr><tr><th>"+(cardsS[i+1])+" S</th>";
        }
    }
    table += "</tr></table>";
}
```

jPunten looks like this:

```
0
    Object { 0="LSZ09 ", 1="1", 2="S", more...} 
0
    "LSZ09 "    
1
    "1" 
2
    "S" 
3
    "0" 
4
    "1" 
5
    "0" 
6
    "I "    
BITNRK
    "1" 
BITSTATUS
    "0" 
DEVPKT
    "1"
KARTNR
    "0"
PKTTYP
    "S"
STATDEV
    "LSZ09 "    
TYPE
    "I "
```

Comment: We're glad you posted your code to generate the table, however where is the code that shows your attempt at what you're trying to accomplish? You're essentially just asking people to do work for you.

Comment: Umm...If I understand correctly, can't you just make a HashMap where the key are the 'PMS03'-things and the value is a list of positions?

Comment: It would be nice if the code was made for me, but that's not what i'm asking for. What i would be really grateful for was if i got some ideas or rather a pathway to follow, as i am rather new to JavaScript. It would be immensely helpful for me to know the best approach for this particular problem.

Comment: @W.K.S I dont think there is something like HashMap in JavaScript

Comment: They're known as associative arrays. It's simply: `map['PMS03']=[{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:2},{x:3,y:7}];`

Comment: @W.K.S Is it also possible to save a string into this like
map['PMS03']=[{label:PMS03-100,ID:124}{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:2},{x:3,y:7}]
?

Comment: `[]` represents an array and `{}` represents an object, so you can have:`map['PMS03']={label:PMS03-100,id: 124,positions:[{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:2},{x:3,y:7}]}`. Here you're storing an object as a value and this object contains the label, id and array of positions.

Comment: @W.K.S And for example if i need map['LSZ09'] i can just acces it like that?
And how would i instantiate the map?

Answer (score 0):

My main suggestion would be to use [underscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/), as it has a lot of useful helper functions for manipulating arrays, saving you a lot of typing. As a solution for the specific problem you are trying to solve, you could use something like this:

```
var arr = [['a', undefined], ['b', 'a']] //2x2 2D test array
var result = _.chain(arr) //Create chainable underscore object
    .map(function(row, j){ //map cell values to objects containing both the value and position in the array
        return _.map(row, function(cell, i){
            return { pos: [i,j], value: cell };
        })
    })
    .flatten() //Put all cells in a single array
    .filter(function(cell){ //Filter the cells based on some criterium
        return cell.value === 'a';
    })
    .map(function(cell){ //Return the position rather than the object we generated
        return cell.pos;
    })
    .value(); //Return the original array instead of the chainable underscore object
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an associative array where the key is 'PMSO3' and the value is an object containg an array of positions.

```
map = [];
map['PMSO3'] = {
    label: 'PMS03-100',
    id: 124,
    positions: [{
        x: 2,
        y: 1
    }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 2
    }, {
        x: 3,
        y: 7
    }]
};

console.log('PMSO3 is located at these positions\n');
map['PMSO3'].positions.forEach(function(aPosition){
    console.log(aPosition.x+' '+aPosition.y+',');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waqqas_abdulkareem/AbYe4/)